# Extend javascript console to add timestamp at the beginning of the log without affecting the log line

Tags: javascript

Below code will maintain the log line as well as the file where this is called from:

```
console.info.bind(console)
```

What I am finding difficult to solve is adding the timestamp at the beginning of the log line without the timestamp being the same everywhere, i tried this approach:

```
export const log = Function.prototype.bind.call(console.info, console, applyTimestamp())
```

[image]

The timestamp is always the same despite the log function being executed at different times. I can see this is due to the applyTimestamp being called at time of declaring log variable. Is it possible to have the timestamp function called the same time console.info is called resulting in different timestamps?

The output "Called from another file" has a set timeout but this will have no effect since applyTime will already have been called.